# How to get signal of qsqldatabase?

Tags: qt, qsqldatabase

I want signal emitted by qsqldatabse object

Eg:
I have 
Qsqldatabase db;

connect (&db, SIGNAL(signal_like_exec()), this, SLOT(any_slot()));

I'm not getting signal in connect() for db

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Whenever any operation on database is done I wanted to execute a function

Comment: So why not just call your function directly after `QSqlDatabase::exec` completes?

Comment: There are many operations at different locations each time I have to call function so I was looking for signal to be connected to function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QSqlDatabase` class does not have signals or slots. Qt event loop and the database are not related in anyway. You only perform operations on data and that's it! Subclassing `QSqlDatabase` and creating custom signals is a bad idea because you wouldn't be able to create and open a connection to the database. So just call your function after `db.open()` returns `true`.